# Three JS How to Rotate Decals while still contouring

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a bunch of decals that are attached to a obj model like below, is there any way to rotate the decals on the model and when they're rotated, they contour to the their new position on the model automatically? I looked all over, every other solution rotates them but they dont contour to the model so they get rendered messed up, I want them to be rotated in place along its center around  z-axis:

```
const decalGeometry = new DecalGeometry(

model,

position,

decalEuler,

decalSize,

);

const decalMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({

map: texture,

transparent: true,

depthTest: true,

depthWrite: false,

polygonOffset: true,

polygonOffsetFactor: -2,

polygonOffsetUnits: -2,

specular: 0x222222,

shininess: 50,

});

const decalMesh = new THREE.Mesh(decalGeometry, decalMaterial);
```

Its very easy to rotate by doing decal.rotation.z += .01; but this does not contour to the model after being rotated nor does it rotate it in place along its center.